# Process freeze( or crash) because of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, processbuilder

This is my code.

```
    ProcessBuilder process = new         
    ProcessBuilder(MyPath);
    Process prp1 = process.start();

    final JFrame frmScanner;
    frmScanner = new JFrame();
    frmScanner.setTitle("Updater");
    frmScanner.setResizable(false);
    frmScanner.setBounds(100, 100, 370, 300);
    frmScanner.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    label1.setBounds(100,50,200,50);
    final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start!!!");
    startButton.setBounds(50, 140, 100, 50);


    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(null);
    p1.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));

    p1.add(startButton);
    p1.add(stopButton);
    frmScanner.add(p1);
    frmScanner.setVisible(true);
```

My process task is collecting data from my project's hardware to text file.

I have tested and found that text file can collect data for only 1KB and then the process hang because of frmScanner.setVisible(true); .

If I manually run the process the process can collect data more than 1KB.
How can I solve this?

Comment: There is nothing I could comment on. You say the process collects data into a file, maybe by redirection? Your code-fragment does not obviously interfere with the process started. I would search in the way your sub-process is called by process-builder to find the issue.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all the UI related stuff (JFrame creation, etc.) on a special separate thread called the EDT. Take a look at the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html .

Comment: The UI thread should not be hindered by a process started in the operating system.

Comment: @thst Could be but doing UI stuff on another thread then the EDT is bound to cause problems non the less. I would fix it first before troubleshooting other problems.